# update_or_create with Django for sum old row

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-queryset

i'm trying to create a row in DATABASE and if exist update the old value to the new + old, with DJANGO. something like PHP above:

```
$sql= "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM April_sales WHERE label='".$product."') THEN
            BEGIN
            UPDATE francais SET sold=sold+'".$sold."'  WHERE label='".$product."';
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO April_sales (sold,sold) VALUES('".$sold."','".$product."');
            END;
            END IF;";
```

i'm receiving new row ,trying this:

```
query = April_sales.objects.get_or_create(product=product, sold= new_amount, date= timezone.now())
sum_value = query.sold + new_amount
query = April_sales(product=product, sold=sum_value , date=timezone.now()) 
query.save()
```

Comment: That code can't work.  `sum_value = query.n+= new_value` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_or_create` of django always returns a tuple, you need two variables to catch what you want:

Try this:

```
query, created = April_sales.objects.get_or_create(product=product)
if created:
    query.sold = new_amount
else:
    query.sold += new_amount
query.date = timezone.now()
query.save()
```

Comment: this look better, just add one line to your code for add date in the if statement

Comment: actually, date is whether it's created or not, we add the timezone.now() to the instance

Answer (score 0):

I found the follow solution, it is not pretty and bit long:
if someone has a better suggestion, feel free to improve.

```
try:
    query = April_sales.objects.get(product=product)
    query.sold = query.sold + new_amount
    query.date = timezone.now()
    query.save()
except April_sales.DoesNotExist:
    query = April_sales(product=product, sold=new_amount, date=timezone.now())
    query.save()
```